# Normal to a 3 Dimensional line

Tags: geometry, 3d

So I have a 3D line: $(0, 0, 0)+t(3, 4, 7)$

and I'm trying to find the normal of this. I know the gradient of the normal would normally be $\frac{-1}{\text{gradient}}$ but I'm not sure how you would find the gradient with 3 dimensions.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: if you mean the normal in the sense of differential geometry, it's a line, hence there is no acceleration and the normal is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

A line in 3D has a normal plane, which is here for instance spanned by the vectors (4,-3,0) and (1,1,-1). Therefore, there is no "the" normal vector. Please provide more context.

Comment: Thanks, how do I work out the normal plane?

Comment: In your example it is any plane with equation 3x+4y+7z=d. I.e., your line is a normal of the plane.

Comment: Where d = distance?

Comment: Sometimes, yes. In general, the plane equation is $ax+by+cz=d$. If $(a,b,c)$ ist normalized, $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, then $d$ is the distance of the plane from the origin. See [Hesse normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesse_normal_form).